# What does 跳马猴子 mean?

Tags: meaning, topolect, idioms

The term literally indicates some kind of monkey jockey riding a racehorse.

I’m guessing it means “lunatic”.

I can’t find it in any dictionary. Any ideas?

Comment: You already got the gist of it. It's a picturesque description of a terrible twos.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be [东北方言 (northeast dialect)](http://www.360doc.com/content/18/0324/11/6956316_739783044.shtml)

> 跳马猴子 - 顽皮淘气的孩子，多指男孩

[and](https://www.docin.com/p-250630652.html)

> '跳马猴子'指不老实的人，特别是小孩儿。如'你一天跳马猴子似的疯跑， 也不知道写作业'。

It's usually used for naughty and active boys.